# About clickable dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I follow this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown) to try to make a clickable dropdown menu.

I notice the code from the link is for one dropdown menu and I think this code is for create the dropdown menu.

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#home">Home</a>
<a href="#about">About</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I try to create another two dropdown menus so I copy the code above twice

```
2nd dropdown 
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown2</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#home">Home2</a>
<a href="#about">About2</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact2</a>
</div>
</div>

3rd dropdown
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown3</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#home">Home2</a>
<a href="#about">About2</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact2</a>
```

I don't edit anything inside the  tag and  tag so I click Run on link to see the result.

Only the first dropdown menu (the original one) can show the menu, the other two dropdown menu do not show anything.

I guess the reason is the second dropdown menu and the third dropdown menu do not have proper content inside the  and  tag.
So I start to modify the code in  and  tag.

Here is the full code the I added for the second dropdown and the third dropdown menu.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

/*1st dropdown*/
.dropbtn {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
padding: 16px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
overflow: auto;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}


/*2nd dropdown*/
.dropbtn2 {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
padding: 16px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn2:hover, .dropbtn2:focus {
background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown2 {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content2 {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
overflow: auto;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content2 a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown2 a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show2 {display:block;}

/*3rd dropdown*/
.dropbtn3 {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
padding: 16px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn3:hover, .dropbtn2:focus {
background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown3 {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content3 {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
overflow: auto;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content3 a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown3 a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show3 {display:block;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

1st dropdown
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#home">Home</a>
<a href="#about">About</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>

2nd dropdown
<div class="dropdown2">
<button onclick="myFunction2()" class="dropbtn2">Dropdown2</button>
<div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content2">
<a href="#home">Home2</a>
<a href="#about">About2</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact2</a>
</div>
</div>

3rd dropdown
<div class="dropdown3">
<button onclick="myFunction3()" class="dropbtn3">Dropdown3</button>
<div id="myDropdown3" class="dropdown-content3">
<a href="#home">Home3</a>
<a href="#about">About3</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact3</a>
</div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  }
  }
  }
  }

//for 2nd dropdown
function myFunction2() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show2");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn2')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content2");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show2')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show2');
  }
}
}
}

//for 3rd dropdown

function myFunction3() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown3").classList.toggle("show3");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn3')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content3");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show3')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show3');
  }
}
}
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the code, all buttons can open the dropdown menu when clicked. However, when I click outside of the dropdown menus, only the third button can close the dropdown menu, the first and the second button still open the dropdown menu.

Here are my questions.

- Copy another two sets of code for create another two dropdown menu seems not a good practice as the code will become messy, not good for debug and even if there is an update, I have change the code multiple times.

However, if don't copy another two sets of code, the other  two dropdown menu will not work.

- Even I copy another two sets of code for create another two dropdown menu, I don't understand the dropdown menus do not close when the mouse click outside of them.

Grateful for your advice please. Thank you.

Comment: You are using 3 times the same id. I think this could cause problems.

Comment: @Huelfe, thanks your comment. I tried different id e.g. <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">, <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content2"> and`<div id="myDropdown3" class="dropdown-content3">`.

Comment: In `<script>` tag about `myFunction`, I put `function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show");
    document.getElementById("myDropdown3").classList.toggle("show");
}`.  When I run the code, I click any button, all of them will open the dropdown menu, if I click outside the dropdown menu, all of them will close together.

Comment: I would like to know how to open the specific dropdown menu by click relevant button? When I click another button, how to close the previous dropdown menu? Do you have any advice please?

Comment: Right now, you are calling the same function, and inside it you are working on all three dropdown elements. Either make three individual functions, or one function that gets a parameter passed to decide _which_ dropdown to work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding three times window.onclick event function. Only the last function launches. If you combine the three functions in one, it works.

Your code now:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

/*1st dropdown*/
.dropbtn {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
padding: 16px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
overflow: auto;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}


/*2nd dropdown*/
.dropbtn2 {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
padding: 16px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn2:hover, .dropbtn2:focus {
background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown2 {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content2 {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
overflow: auto;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content2 a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown2 a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show2 {display:block;}

/*3rd dropdown*/
.dropbtn3 {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
padding: 16px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn3:hover, .dropbtn2:focus {
background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown3 {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content3 {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
overflow: auto;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content3 a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown3 a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show3 {display:block;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

1st dropdown
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="#home">Home</a>
<a href="#about">About</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
</div>

2nd dropdown
<div class="dropdown2">
<button onclick="myFunction2()" class="dropbtn2">Dropdown2</button>
<div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content2">
<a href="#home">Home2</a>
<a href="#about">About2</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact2</a>
</div>
</div>

3rd dropdown
<div class="dropdown3">
<button onclick="myFunction3()" class="dropbtn3">Dropdown3</button>
<div id="myDropdown3" class="dropdown-content3">
<a href="#home">Home3</a>
<a href="#about">About3</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact3</a>
</div>
</div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

//for 2nd dropdown
function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown2").classList.toggle("show2");
}



//for 3rd dropdown

function myFunction3() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown3").classList.toggle("show3");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
    }
  }
  
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn2')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content2");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show2')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show2');
        }
    }
  }
  
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn3')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content3");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show3')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show3');
        }
    }
  }
}




</script>
</body>
</html>
```